# How to set the custom made ringtone as ringtone of a phone

Tags: lumia

I installed the App ringtone maker and made a custom ringtone of 20 seconds. I saved it and set the same as my ring tone. But Unfortunately, that ringtone is not playing, i tried two three different songs but i cannot set that customised part of song as my ringtone , what can be the problem here ?

Comment: When you say that you cannot **"set that customised part of song"** as your ringtone, do you mean it does not show in the list of ringtones or does it not work once you have selected it? Why don't you just connect your windows phone to your PC and add any music you want to the **Ringtones** folder, it will be viewed by WP as custom ringtone and will be added to the list of rigntones.

Comment: Did you checked the Ringtones folder for these ringtone files and verified that it's not corrupted?

Comment: Try doing this through your PC and paste song you want to be on your ringtone to **Ringtone** folder in your phone.

Comment: An alternative solution : UC browser app has an option to set the downloaded song as ring tone.

Comment: What ringtone maker are you using, @BharatBachani?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest you to try **Ringtone Maker** app by microsoft it worked fine for me.
Now if you are using a pc ringtone maker just take care of these restrictions
A MP3 or WMA file
Not protected with digital rights management (DRM)
Less than 1 MB in size
Less than 40 seconds
Must have the genre "ringtone"
File must be copied directly from PC to phone's Music or Ringtones folder